# Debugging HTTPS requests/responses with Fiddler on Android Phone don`t work

Tags: android, web, https, fiddler, traffic

everytime i try to debug HTTPS traffic (on my android phone) from a specific host, i get the following error message in fiddler inspector window.

```
After the client received notice of the established CONNECT, it failed to send any data.
```

Can you tell me, what i did wrong? I debug web requests on my samsung galaxy s2. In web session window, i can see all requests. In the inspector window i get something like this:

```
CONNECT example-site.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: example-site.com
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; GT-I9100 Build/IMM76L)
Connection: Keep-Alive
After the client received notice of the established CONNECT, it failed to send any data.
```

Response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 12:39:43.452
Connection: close
```

I successfully install fiddler root certificate for decrpyt https. Also debuging same web traffic from pc chrome browser works fine (I can see request/response SOAP/REST body`s in detail). Where is the difference from pc to android?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

I expect this has been resolved by now, but for those having a similar problem with Chrome for Android (which I *think* is the issue here, as Chrome on PC is mentioned as fine), there is a setting called Bandwidth Management.

If you have Bandwidth Management enabled then traffic will go through Google proxy servers. You need to switch this off.

Launch Chrome and in Settings go to Bandwidth Management under Advanced. Turn off Preload webpages and Reduce data usage.